# unable to pass information to callback function

Tags: python, lambda, callback, tkinter, partial

I am using Tkinter,python 2.7 and am new to gui programming. I want to pass a string to a callback function in a button.I have tried both partial from functools and lambda functions. So far no luck. So I must be doing something wrong.

```
    def fetch_urls(name):
        print name        

    root=Tk()
    aname=StringVar()
    E1 = Entry(root, bd =5,textvariable=aname,justify=CENTER,width=20)
    E1.grid(row=0,column=1,columnspan=3)

    fetchbutton=Button(root,text ="FETCH",command =fetch_urls)
    fetchbutton.grid(row=7,column=0)
```

what I basically want is to send the string in aname ie the text in the entry widget E1 to the function fetch_urls. I have tried the following with no success

1) using lambda

```
    anime=aname.get()
    lambdafetch=lambda: fetch_urls(anime)
    fetchbutton=Button(root,text ="FETCH",command =lambdafetch)
```

2)using partial from functools

```
    anime=aname.get()
    parfetch=partial(fetch_urls,anime)
    fetchbutton=Button(root,text ="FETCH",command =parfetch)
```

In both cases the string is not passed to the function. I would like to know what I am doing wrong and how to make it work.

```
    def fetch():
        fetch_urls(aname.get())
    fetchbutton=Button(root,text ="FETCH",command =fetch)
```

this works(got the idea 15 mins after posting the question). but surely this can't be the only way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that with both `lambda` and `partial` you are evaluating `aname` at the time the callback is created, instead of being evaluated at the time it is actually called.

For `partial`, you would need to modify the `fetch_urls` function to actually eval the value:

```
def fetch_urls(aStringVar):
    print aStringVar.get()   

parfetch = partial(fetch_urls, aname)
```

For `lambda`, just have it evaluate the object:

```
lambdafetch = lambda: fetch_urls(aname.get())
```

But I tend to not use `lambda` for callbacks because you might run into scope issues. You may have to use a trick to "capture" the `aname` object:

```
lambdafetch = lambda s=aname: fetch_urls(s.get())
```

Comment: Thank you. This completely solves the problem i have been having.I should have tried it myself.:)